# CSS, how to differentiate between Ios and android?

Tags: android, ios, css, media-queries

I currently have a program that uses an `iframe` to load a webpage.

This webpage is styled with a normal `CSS` file. I use media queries to change the styling for mobile devices.

I've stumbled on a problem where my media query works for android but not for an `Ios` screen.

Then if I change the CSS it works for `Ios` but not for android.

Is there a way to write two separate media queries. One for android devices and another for `Ios`?

I'd really appreciate some help!

**EDIT:**

I've added some CSS code:

```
/* ----------------- Mobile css ----------------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {   
    #payment-submit {
    line-height:50px;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    /* Safari 5+ ONLY */
    ::i-block-chrome, #payment-submit {
     line-height:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all: you can sniff the user agent string. But such practice is very much discouraged, since you should design and develop your website as client-unaware as possible. Secondly: can you please post the bits of code that only work on either iOS or Android?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should apply css media query based on browser i.e. (Safari for iPhones & Chrome for Android devices). Now you need to apply media queries only. Below is the CSS for the same.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    /* Safari and Chrome, if Chrome rule needed */
    .someClass {
     color:#c00;
    }
    /* Safari 5+ ONLY */
    ::i-block-chrome, .someClass {
     color:#000;
    }
}
```

Also [this](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/) and [this](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/CSS-hack-for-Safari-Browser-672.php) links can help you out for the same.

Hope this helps :)